# Find improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Find improper integral  $\int_{0}^{1}-\frac{\log(x)}{x^2}\cdot (xe)^\frac{1}{x}dx$.

I used the following substitution  $t=\frac{1}{x}$,

$x=\frac{1}{t}\mspace{10mu},dx=-x^2dt,\mspace{10mu} \log(x)=-\log(t)$.

$\int_{0}^{1}-\frac{\log(x)}{x^2}\cdot (xe)^\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}\log(t)(\frac{e}{t})^t dt$

How do I continue?

Comment: Could you provide some context?

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=e^z$ and $dx=e^zdz$. Then
$$
-\int _{0}^{1} \frac{\log(x)}{x^2} (xe)^{x^{-1}}\,dx =
$$
$$
=- \int _{-\infty}^{0} e^{e^{-z} (z+1)-z} z\,dz 
$$
$$
= \left.e^{e^{-z} (z+1)}\right|_{-\infty}^{0} = e-0=e
$$

Comment: Or just observe that 
$$
\left(f(x)^{1/x}\right)' = f(x)^{1/x}\left(\frac{-f(x)\log(f(x))+x f'(x)}{x^2 f(x)}\right)
$$Here you have $f(x)=xe$, so the derivative simplifies to
$$
(xe)^{1/x} \left(\frac{-ex \log(x)-ex+ex}{x^2 \cdot ex}\right) = (xe)^{1/x} \left(\frac{- \log(x)}{x^2}\right),
$$which is exactly the integrand.